# Implementation Tree and other data structure with ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new Ruby programmar. when I was in C++ I could implement data structures with pointer but now in Ruby I don't know how can I implement these data structures ( for example tree ).
Can someone help me ( for example introduce me a good reference or take a good example ).
Special thanks.

Comment: Do you want to associate ActiveRecord objects or is the question only Ruby oriented?

Comment: Excuse me , I don't meaning of some expression in your comment like ActiveRecoed . can you explain more clearly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing tree with Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196430/implementing-tree-with-ruby)

Answer (score 10):

Ruby doesn't have nor need pointers since most things are simply passed by reference.

```
> a = "hello"
> b = a
> a.object_id == b.object_id
=> true
```

In its simplest form a tree node could just be a struct, with a parent and a left and right sibling:

```
> Node = Struct.new(:parent, :left, :right)
> root = Node.new
> n1   = Node.new(root, "hello", "world")
> root.left = n1
...

> root.left.left
=> "hello"
> root.left.right
=> "world"
```

For more complete implementations you could look at for example:

RubyTree:
http://rubytree.rubyforge.org/rdoc/

SimpleTree:
https://github.com/ealdent/simple-tree/blob/master/lib/simple_tree.rb